# Haskell: Constructing an class constrained abstract data type like numbers

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

When I create a number like:

```
x = 1
y = 2
z = 3
```

The type of these variables is like so:

```
ghci> :t x
ghci> Num a => a
```

This makes me think that 1 is a "data constructor" which constructs not a type, nor a type constructor, but any type that is constrained by `Num` class. This allows me to further clarify to the compiler which of the `Num a` that I want by running `x :: Int` or `x :: Integer`.

I tried finding out how this is done in the docs, but no luck.

So the question is, how would one be able to create a similar data type? In other words, how can I create a set of data constructors similar to `1,2,3,4,5...` that creates a value of type `MyOwnClass a => a`, where `MyOwnClass` is any arbitrary class that I created myself?

For example:

```
x = A
y = д
z = Ψ

ghci> :t x
ghci> Alphabet a => a
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Numbers are special.  The class `Num` has a `fromInteger` method which implements the interpretation of numbers. So when you see `1729`, it's short for `fromInteger 1729`, where that second `1729` is the literal `Integer`.  You can't create such a magical interpretation yourself for things other than numbers (and strings, given the `OverloadedStrings` extension).

That said, if the alphabet you are interested in is finite, you can do this using the usual typeclass machinery, as long as you follow the syntactical rules of the language (e.g. variables must start with lowercase letters):

```
class Alphabet t where
    a :: t
    b :: t
    ...
```

Now

```
ghci> :t a
a :: (Alphabet t) => t
```

Comment: So I can use `a` without even declaring it as a data constructor?

Comment: Its appearance in the `class` definition is a declaration. . . although for it to mean something, you'll have to define at least one instance of `Alphabet`.

Comment: Why can't I use a capital `A`? Yes I get it's reserved for data constructors, but this `A` looks like a data constructor!

Comment: It may look like one but it is not.  You cannot pattern match on `a` for example.   We could declare `instance Alphabet (Int -> Int) where a = id; b = (+1)` and then these would surely not be data constructors.

Comment: I see. What if I were to use Template Haskell? Would it be possible then?

Comment: Uh... I don't see what that has to do with it.  New question maybe?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74325/discussion-between-luqui-and-cmcdragonkai).

Answer (score 1):

```
class Alphabet t where
    a :: t

instance Alphabet Int where
    a = 1

x = a

ghci> :t x
ghci> Alphabet t => t
```

This is just how typeclasses work :)

Comment: What is `A : t`? That's not the same as `term :: type-sig` right?

Comment: `A` is an uppercase letter and so refers to a constructor, so it can't be a member of a type class. Technicalities, technicalities...